# how to implement timer with interval in C++

Tags: c++, timer

I am writing a program in C++ where I need to call a function in every 250 ms. It is really easy in C#, but i don't have much idea how to implement that in C++.

I would really appreciate if anyone could suggest me the solution.

Comment: Do you just need to wait around in a busy loop, or do you need to get anything else done in the meantime? In the latter case you'll either need some multithreading, or your main even loop just needs to check every time whether the interval is up.

Comment: Do you have any links to implement that using multithreading?

Comment: There's no one-size-fits-all recipe to multithreading. Boost.ASIO has a ready-made timer thing and you could run the ASIO service in a separate thread, or you could roll your own sleeping function and launch it using `<thread>`... you'll have to find a way to sleep for short times, which I think is platform dependent (in Linux you have `usleep`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [SetTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx) function is used to create a Windows timer.

Comment: This is not standard C++.

Comment: @Alex no it's not, but the context of the question made it sound like they were using Windows. If the newer updates to C++ added a standard way to do this cross-platform, you're free to write your own answer. Let me know if you do so I can look at it.

Comment: If I wanted to answer to OP, I would not provide a non standard C++ function. I would take the time to explain a way to do so in standard C++. Period. Serious programmers deserve to know that your answer is not standard C++, hence my comment. Take it the way you wish, I don't really care.

Comment: @Alex I'm still not aware of a way to do this in standard C++, so I did the next best thing. If the goal is to solve an immediate problem, whether something is part of the standard or not makes little difference. I was not trying to put you down when I suggested writing your own answer, I was serious. Most of what I know of C++11 and later I learned on StackOverflow, and there's still gaps.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into something called delta timing.  This is used in game programming to keep the framerate from going out of control.  This is needed because different machines run different hardware and will therefore run at different speeds.  So the 250ms that you're looking for maybe x number of cycles on one machine, but when you go to another machine, it may be y number of cycles.

Answer (score 0):

> A waitable timer object is a synchronization object whose state is set to signaled when the specified due time arrives. There are two types of waitable timers that can be created: manual-reset and synchronization. A timer of either type can also be a periodic timer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687012(v=vs.85).aspx